# How do I avoid java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when submitting Spark job on EMR cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have Spark application that runs successfully on my local machine. I use Hbase Docker container, from which I load the data to my Spark app. Now I have created EMR cluster with Spark and Hbase installed. Buy when I'm trying to submit my JAR file I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

When running my app locally, I was able to avoid this kind of error by adding `--jars` flag to `spark-submit`, giving Spark the path to all Hbase Jars.

1. How could I overcome this error when running on EMR?
2. Should I re-direct Spark to Hbase jar's in EMR as well? Where those jars located on EMR cluster?

   ```
       Configuration hBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
       hBaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "MyTable");

   JavaRDD<String> myStrings = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
       hBaseConf, TableInputFormat.class,ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class).keys().map(key -> {
           String from = Bytes.toString(key.get());
           return from;
       });
     .
     .
     .
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate the JAR's on EMR shell with hbase classpath command. Then I took Hbase path to jars and added to spark-submit with --jars flag.